# What impacts stocking times?

Tags: tiny-tower

You can upgrade your shops to Level 2, Level 3, ...ect. Now correct me if I'm wrong, but upgrading the shop adds quanitity to your restocking, meaning you get more stock for every restock. However, does upgrading the shop also lower the amount of time it takes to stock an item? Or does every shop have their own stock time regaurdless of the level of the shop.

Also, does the *type* of shop have anything to do with stock times? For example, do food types tend to stock faster/slower than recreation and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Wiki:](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Floor_Upgrades#Floor_Upgrades)

> At the cost of 3 Tower Bux, the player can permanently upgrade a commercial floor. Each level of upgrade does the following:
>    - Adds 75 Stock to each product
>    - Adds 45 Coins to the cost of restocking each product
>    - Adds 5 minutes to the restocking time of each product

Upgrading is thus best used for low-stock floors as you can boost their stock by the largest relative amount and increase their stocking time to something more sane. Type of floor is irrelevant, and there doesn't seem to be a max floor level either. Just upgrade low-stock floors to the point where you can comfortably restock at your own pace.

Note Dream Job stocks are actually boosted by 150 stock, the 75 stock boost is applied before the Dream Job multiplier.

Comment: So basically by upgrading the level you are ADDING time that it takes to stock the product.

Comment: Yes, but you also get more stock. Upgrading is useful if you find a floor gets out of stock too quickly for your liking.

Comment: @Emerica. yep, no free rides. I think the time it adds is perfectly in sync with the time it normally takes to stock 75 stock worth of items. It's still good though because it's typically impossible to keep Food stores stocked because of crazy low stock levels.

Comment: @BenBrocka So then there is a correlation between stock levels and shop types?

Comment: @Emerica. sort of, but not strictly. Food type floors tend to have low stock/restock time. Creative floors tend to have the longest. There are outliers for every store type, but Food floors are the strongest correlation, very few Food stores have stock times at/over an hour.